# FFT values computed using Python and MATLAB don't match?

Tags: python, matlab, fft

I have a super simple test code to compute FFT in MATLAB, which I am trying to convert to Python but the computed values do not match.

**MATLAB Code:**

```matlab
rect=zeros(100,1);
ffrect=zeros(100,1);
for j=45:55
    rect(j,1)=1;
end

frect=fft(rect);
```

**Python Code**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fftshift, ifftshift

rect = np.zeros((100, 1))

for j in range(44, 55):
   rect[j] = 1

frect = fft(rect)
```

**Problem:**

The computed values of `frect` computed using MATLAB and Python do not match (or even look similar). The values computed by Python has only zero values for complex component and 1s for real.

Comment: D'oh! You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scipy.fft.fft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fft.html#scipy.fft.fft) computes the FFT over the last axis unless you specify otherwise with the `axis` parameter.

In the Python version, your input array is of shape `(100, 1)`, so you're computing 100 different 1-point FFTs.

To compute a single 100-point FFT, either

- reshape `rect` to have its 100 entries in the last dimension (for example, by making it a 1D vector with shape `(100,)`, or a 2D single-row array with shape `(1, 100)`), or
- pass `axis=0` when calling `scipy.fft.fft`

```py
fft(rect.reshape(-1))
# or
fft(rect, axis=0)
```

Comment: Or just start with `rect = np.zeros(100)`, or use `fft(rect, axis=0)`.

Comment: I changed first statement to `rect = np.zeros(100)` and the results look fine. Thanks :)